# Questions regarding voltage divider for micro controller sensing

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-divider, attiny85

I am beginner trying to develop two voltage sensors for attiny85 microcontroller. I have two separate voltage levels that I want to sense using the attiny. One of the voltage supply is 0V-5.5V and is fluctuating very often within that range, and I want to detect the voltage every second or so through attiny85 analogread function and record it inside a log. I want to use the VS1 sense line from the schematic and connect it directly to any analog pin of the attiny85. And the SIN is directly connected to the supply voltage. On the other supply, I have linear 0V-2.7V which is connected directly to the CVP pin. And the VS2 is connected directly to another analog pin of the attiny85.

The attiny85 is being powered by a separate 3.3V supply. And the reference voltage I want to use is 1.35V inside the software. So, 0V-1.35V inside the attiny analogread to detect this 0V-5.5V fluctuating range and 0V-2.7V linear range.

Now, the questions:
1. Is my voltage divider circuits feasible and a good approach for these two types of voltage measurements?
2. Is it possible to improve the voltage sense circuitry, to get better accurate readings?
3. What high quality good brand SMD components I could use for these voltage sense circuits and their eagle library parts suggestions?

[image: Included inside the question]

Any suggestions and tips would be highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: What is 'fluctuating very often'? `R1` and `C1` create a low pass filter of about 2Hz

Comment: the voltage going into SIN is fluctuating very often. I mean it can go to 5V and then suddenly drop to 2V and then within seconds can go back upto 5V again. The suddenly 0V. Hope you got the point. It is not entirely oscillating in high frequency. It is a variable unpredictable voltage supply.

Comment: Ok, with the setup now, the voltage divider will have a slow respons. So sudden changes won't be recorded directly or eg. spikes will be missed. To have a faster respons you can decrease the capacitor value.

Comment: The ADC system of the Attiny85 has selectable references of 1.1V, 2.56V, and Vcc.  If you use the 2.56V reference you can also add an optional capacitor filter onto the reference pin (when selected). Using the higher reference voltage will improve the circuit's noise immunity.

Comment: According to stefan's suggestion I will change the capacitor value to 100nF @Swedgin.

Comment: @Nedd I want to use software based references rather than tweaking attiny85 register values for selectable references on ADC. That might also cost me another reference pin right?

Comment: @Farukh Yeah, didn't see stefan suggested a 100nF cap. I would also take a cap of that order

Comment: And if you want to limit the current into the attiny you can add a buffer between the divider and the attiny

Comment: @Swedgin as far my calculations go, only 191uA max is going in to the attiny85 analog pin if I consider the pin as high impedance. I do not know, if that amount of current will hurt the pin in any way. Also, am not sure what kind of buffer you are talking about. An opamp buffer comes into my mind and if I do that, then aren't I potentially loosing overall efficiency on the circuit because the opamp needs external power of couple of mA? Also need to search for a buffer which will support 0V on the output pin.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed a 10^3 factor. In your situation it's idd maybe an overkill. But if you find problems with your current setup (like crosstalk, instability, wrong conversions,..) I'd add the buffer. And yes a buffer consisting of an opamp (and it should be rail-to-rail if you want 0V included).

Comment: @Swedgin I did not get your reference idd. What do you mean exactly by that? And could you please put up an answer showing an example schematic implementing my provided schematic with the added buffer in place? Also, a good quality smd component suggestion for that buffer would be really appreciated. And does adding this buffer will allow me to exclude any zener clamping for voltage spikes? Sorry for these follow up questions, but I am actually a total beginner in electronics design and I am still learning the correct ways to do things.

Comment: @Farukh, adding a reference filter cap would require use of an extra ADC input pin, but the attiny85 does have a total of 4 available.  Regardless, using a higher reference voltage either through software or hardware would allow a higher input voltage that would put the ADC steps further above any potential system noise.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your voltage divider circuits seam OK to me. Given that there are no
   other requirements, this is a feasible way of measuring these
   voltages.
2. Your question is too unspecific. It is always possible to improve
   something. It depends on what your requirements are. With the 10bit
   ADC of the Attiny85 you have a theoretical signal to noise ratio of
   60.2dB. So this is the best you can do with this ADC converter.
3. If you want low temperature drift and tight tolerances, you can use C0G/NP0 type SMD parts. I would use a unpolarized cermic cap with much lower capacity (100nF), e.g. this one [GRM31C5C1H104JA01L](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/GRM31C5C1H104JA01L/490-6505-1-ND/3845702?utm_campaign=buynow&WT.z_cid=ref_octopart_dkc_buynow&utm_medium=aggregator&curr=eur&site=us&utm_source=octopart). But I think that also an X7R rated (standard) SMD ceramic capacitor could be OK for your application. For resistor, you could use this one (10K, 1%, 1206 case size): [CRG1206F10K](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/CRG1206F10K/A106069CT-ND/3477720?utm_campaign=buynow&WT.z_cid=ref_octopart_dkc_buynow&utm_medium=aggregator&curr=eur&site=us&utm_source=octopart). Please be aware that there are a lot of capacitors or resistors that could fit your application.

Comment: 3. Can you please guide me on the specific part numbers for the capacitor and resistors on the C0G/NP0 class. I am very beginner to SMD electronics. So, it would be really helpful to refer to part numbers directly and then implement them in eagle.

2. As I stated my requirements in the question. Just need to measure a non-linear flactuating voltage using VS1 and a linear one using VS2. And I have provided the range of voltage that is needed to be measured in both cases.

Comment: Also, any suggestion on the type of capacitor I should use in this case? How much voltage rating, what type?  tantalum, ceramic, film, electrolytic and polarized or non-polarized?

Comment: 3. I updated the answer regarding the capacitor suggestion.

Comment: thanks for the update. if possible please update the answer with a resistor suggestion also. And what do you think of adding a zener clamp in this circuit?

Comment: Of course you could add a zener clamp too, if you need to protect the circuit.

Comment: Should I be worried about the piezoelectric effect of the ceramic cap? Because the board will be placed closer to a circuitry cooling fan.

Comment: Stefan, Could you please suggest me a high quality smd zener for this application with it's resistor type and value and how should I go about connecting it in the existing circuit design? And any info about how much voltage spike it might be able to handle before destroying itself or the attiny85 would be really appreciated.